# install midi, midi_maniulation on Linux for python3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, midi

I have seen answers here but couldn't find one that solved my issue. I want to install midi, midi_manipulation for python3 on Linux. This is what I have tried uptil now:-

```
sudo pip3 install python3-midi
sudo pip install midi_manipulation
sudo pip install midi
sudo pip3 install midi
sudo pip install python-midi
```

I have downloaded other packages using the exact same format and just the different package name but why isn't it working for midi? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no `midi_manipulation` at PyPI (do you know where from `pip` installs packages?) and there is [package midi](https://pypi.org/project/midi/) but it doesn't contain any downloadable files. The only way is to download source code from [release](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi/releases/tag/v0.2.3) or install directly from Github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi.git#egg=midi
```

Comment: First you have to find it. Where from you get the name?